# Pure native compilation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

With Xamarin, is it possible to have a 'pure' native compilation?

What I mean by this is, if I write in Xamarin C# my own `class MyView : UIView` I'd like it to be compiled as usual but without having Xamarin create managed wrappers for it. I'd like to have it compiled to the native bits as if it was written in ObjectiveC or Java.

Of course, it depends a lot of the .NET code I choose to write in that class, but let's suppose I don't have any specific .NET code, just using the Xamarin native API.

This could have tremendous benefits in terms of perf on Android

Comment: Xamarin is not a transcoding build system, it will always require a Mono/.Net runtime. If you want "pure native", you would need to use "native" tooling.

Answer (score 0):

If you think avoiding garbage collection and managed classes, then no and it will probably never be possible because Xamarin was built exactly for this purpose and it is in its foundations. Though on Android most software is written in Java/Kotlin and they have the garbage collection.

Otherwise if you think running the native code without interpreter then yes it is called AOT compilation. It is on by default on iOS for release projects and on Android the partial AOT is on by default for release projects. If you want the full AOT on Android you need to have Visual Studio Enterprise license.

And it doesn't depend on the using of .NET classes at all.